# How to "mark" a section of text in a Word document, so that it can be easily deleted using Interop.Word

Tags: c#, cpu-word, word-interop

I have a Word document that is used both for emailing and digital signing. When used for digital signing, a section of text in the document should be removed.

How (in Word) do I "mark" this section - without it being visible when the document is emailed - so that I can find it and delete it, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Thanks, guys.

Comment: _"How (in Word) do I "mark" this section...using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?"_ - did you try anything? Any code to show?

Comment: @MickyD in the document i'm using fields like this to add values using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word: { DOCVARIABLE \Name }. Im looking for a field like this, to mark a section of the document, so that I can find and delete it programmatically.